# Rails - using text_field as value of data attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a button that shows a bootstrap popover appears with a text field when clicked that that a user can type out an email address of the person they want to share a post with. 
Here's the code so far for the button:

```
  <%= link_to collab_user_stories_path(@post), class: 'btn btn-default', title: 'Enter the email of the person you want to share this with:', 'data-toggle' => 'popover', 'data-trigger' => 'focus', 'data-html' => 'true', 'data-content' => '<%= text_field_tag :user %>' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;Collaborate with...
  <% end %>
```

I'm getting an error with the `'data-content' => '<%= text_field_tag :user %>'` part.
 It says: "unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' "
I've tried `'data-content' => '#{<%= text_field_tag :user %>}'` and still get the same error.
Anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: You can't use `'#{<%= text_field_tag :user %>}'`, instead you should use `"#{<%= text_field_tag :user %>}"`. Use double quotes when there are variables to be evaluated in the string.

Comment: @HassanAkram And you don't need either since you're already in Ruby code-just `text_field_tag(:user)` is sufficient. And trying to use both string interpolation *and* erb output certainly won't work.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes you are absolutely right. I was just correcting his line `'#{<%= text_field_tag :user %>}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line should be this:

```
<%= link_to collab_user_stories_path(@post), 
      title: 'Enter the email of the person you want to share this with:', 
      'data-toggle' => 'popover', 
      'data-trigger' => 'focus', 
      'data-html' => 'true', 
      'data-content' => text_field_tag( :user ),
      class: 'btn btn-default', do %>
```

As is, you're trying to embed erb tags within erb, which won't work.

Also, you might try making class: 'btn btn-default', the final hash key/value in your link_to tag.

Comment: ah your first answer worked best for me! having `'data-content' => "#{text_field_tag(:user)}"`. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You're already using ruby code when you're adding that `data-content`, so you don't need to have another set of `<%= %>`, you're already inside them!

You need to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to (...) 'data-content' => text_field_tag(:user) do %>
```

I believe this should work, I've done something similar in the past

Keep in mind that the moment you enter into `<%= %>` tags in a `.erb` file, you are writing strictly ruby code.

You wouldn't do this in ruby:

```
{
  'data-content' => '<%= my_method(:param) %>'
}
```

So, you shouldn't do that in the ruby code in your template either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to collab_user_stories_path(@post), class: 'btn btn-default', title: 'Enter the email of the person you want to share this with:', data: { toggle: "popover", trigger: "focus", html: "true", content: text_field_tag(:user) } do %>
    <%= content_tag :span, "Collaborate with...", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" %>
<% end %>
```

Since you're using `erb`, you won't need to re-parse `text_field_tag`, but rather just include it as an argument to your `link_to` method. You also need to be aware that the [`data` attribute of `link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) should be passed as a hash.